# Binomial logistic regression graph interpretation

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, logistic-regression, binomial-coefficients

I am working on a binomial logistic regression analysis with one categorical dependent variable, one continuous independent variable, and one indicator variable. I have run the regression, and created plots. I think I have done everything correctly, however, I am put off a little bit by the look of my plots. This is how my plots look (Note, the red dotted line is the indicator variable. It is not included in the code further down.):

[image: Practical example]

And this is how I was thought in school that they were going to look:

[image: Academic example]

Here is a reproducible sample:

```
sample = data.frame(AWO = sample(0:1,1000, T),
                    corn = rnorm(1000, 0, 1))
```

Here are the code I applied:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(sample, aes(x=corn, y=AWO)) +
      geom_point(alpha = .25) +
      geom_smooth(method = "glm", 
                  method.args = list(family = "binomial"), 
                  se = FALSE)
```

I have also performed and plotted the regression manually and get the same results, for those interested:

```
mwc <- glm(AWO ~ corn, data = sample, family=binomial)
x0 = seq(min(sample$corn), max(sample$corn), length = 1000)
plot(sample$corn, sample$AWO)
pwc = predict(mwc, newdata = data.frame(corn = x0), type = "response")
lines(x0, pwc)
```

So my question is, have I plotted the regression wrong, or is it simply a case of academia v. practice?

Comment: I think your plotting code is correct, it might be more about 'textbook' examples are idealised scenarios whereas your real data might not be. If you look at your plots, the upper and lower point clouds mostly overlap one another, so there might not be a lot to predict from it.

Comment: @teunbrand Thanks for your response. I thought this was the case, but I wasn't sure. If I am not mistaken, this plot shows that the blue line (dummy = 0) is closer to Y = 0 and the red dotted line (dummy = 1) is closer to Y = 1 (for most cases). So in at least three out of five cases we see that the dummy variable shifts the intercept upwards, but does not significantly impact the slope.

Comment: This has certainly been asked before, either here or on CrossValidated, but not sure I can find it quickly ...

Comment: @BenBolker You would certainly think so, but I wasn't able to find this question precisely on either platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of outcome just doesn't change much over the range of your data, so you only have a small section of the idealised curve. Let's take your example:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)

sample <- data.frame(AWO = sample(0:1,1000, T),
                    corn = rnorm(1000, 0, 1))

myplot <- ggplot(sample, aes(x=corn, y=AWO)) +
   geom_point(alpha = .25) +
   geom_smooth(method = "glm", 
               method.args = list(family = "binomial"), 
               se = FALSE, fullrange = TRUE)

myplot
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

But now let's zoom out on the x axis:

```r
myplot + xlim(c(-100, 100))
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In your sample data (and presumably your real data) there is no relationship (or a very weak relationship) between `corn` and `AWO`.  If you simulate some data that has `AWO` depending on `corn` then you get a graph like you expect:

```
sample = data.frame(corn = rnorm(1000, 0, 1))
sample$AWO <- rbinom(1000,1,  exp(sample$corn)/(1+exp(sample$corn))  )

ggplot(sample, aes(x=corn, y=AWO)) +
  geom_point(alpha = .25) +
  geom_smooth(method = "glm", 
              method.args = list(family = "binomial"))
```

[image]

Comment: Agreed. OP, your analysis is done correctly; your data just has no relationship. That's why your logistic curves just look like linear regressions.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I marked Allan's response as the one which solved my issue because it was more in depth, but this was also really helpful.